# Desconectar xampp de workbench

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

hace tiempo conecte workbench para trabajar con xampp. Actualmente quiero trabajar únicamente con el workbench de mysql, el problema es que aún se requiere la conexión de xampp.

Desinstale xampp y reinstale el server de mysql, me dejo trabajar bien en ese momento, sin xampp, pero ahora que intento abrir nuevamente el servidor mysql, me dice que no se puede establecer conexión.

Alguien sabrá como solucionar esto?

Comment: te sirve la consola de mysql ? para hacer consultas y eso? (para descartar que inicia todo bien pero no conecta con tu base en el workbench o se daño la base de mysql )

Comment: Eso no lo intente, pero estoy casi seguro de que el problema es que se deniega la conexión, porque al intentar acceder con cmd me aparece, ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061). Como si hubiera otro servidor activo.

Comment: has probado cambiar la carpeta mysql con el bu de mysql??? lo encontre hace tiempo en un foro te lo pongo aca  SOLUCION : Por favor no borres el archivo ibdata1, esto podría dejar inservibles tus bases de datos.
-cierra el proceso mysql
-Cambia el nombre de la carpeta mysql/data por mysql/data_old o el nombre que desees.
-Crea una nueva carpeta mysql/data
-Copia el contenido de mysql/backup en la carpeta mysql/data
-Copia todas las carpetas de tus bases de datos de mysql/data_old a mysql/data (no copies las carpetas mysql, performance_schema, ni phpmyadmin)

Comment: -Finalmente copia el archivo ibdata1 de mysql/data_old a mysql/data.
-Inicia MySQL en el panel de control XAMPP
 y listo 

Comment: Gracias, al final elimine y reinstale el server nuevamente. Creo que el problema fue que, la primera vez que reinstale el server, guarde la contraseña para que se iniciara el servidor automáticamente. Esta vez la ingreso yo manualmente cada que necesito abrirlo y ahora me funciona con normalidad.

Comment: ah bueno me alegro, igual guarda esos pasos que ami me a pasado que por las bases mas que nada uno aveces no se reinstala el server completo, y con eso se guardan las bases y contraseña y todo , saludos!!